# Is there an "comprehensive" list of Tironian symbols?

Tags: cicero, font

I am willing to create a font family for typesetting tironian notes.
To do so, I am looking for a list of the symbols used (especially during Roman times) as comprehensive as possible.
The Wikipedia pages in the languages I know give a bunch of examples but they are missing a lot of them.

Answer (score 6):

The bottom of the Wikipedia article [Tironian notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes) includes a link to Wilhelm Schmitz's edition of the *[Commentarii notarum tironianarum](https://archive.org/details/commentariinotar00schm/page/n1/mode/2up).* I apologize if you've already seen it, but in case you have not, it includes many notes, including ones that are not attested in actual use outside of the list. Some are likely to be post-Roman inventions. I'm not familiar with any more complete list.

Here is a blog post I found giving some background on manuscripts of the *Commentarii*: "[An ancient handbook of short-hand: Tironian notes and the “Commentarii notarum Tironianarum](https://www.roger-pearse.com/weblog/2019/08/14/an-ancient-handbook-of-short-hand-tironian-notes-and-the-commentarii-notarum-tironianarum/)", by Roger Pearse (August 14, 2019)